# iMacros - How to follow a link from a Plain Text Div

Tags: javascript, imacros

Suppose a HTML page contains following codes:

```
<div>
        Please follow the link below
        https://www.website.com/register/verify.php/0jdJcPDJPr31sXgRQEvw5OY97FgUfS.<br></div>
```

How can I tell iMacros to follow the URL which is present in the above DIV.

iMacro has to open the following URL in the current tab:

```
https://www.website.com/register/verify.php/0jdJcPDJPr31sXgRQEvw5OY97FgUfS
```

Please note that there is no A HREF in this, and it's just plain text. There is also a DOT at the end of the URL which must be discarded while opening the link.

I tried the following, without any success:

```
var confirmAcc;
confirmAcc =  "CODE:";
confirmAcc +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Please<SP>follow<SP>the<SP>link<SP>below*" + "\n";
iimPlay(confirmAcc);
```

This is just highlighting the DIV, and not following the URL in it.

Any help would be highly appreciated, as I have spent numerous hours trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this macro:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:"Please follow the link below*" EXTRACT=TXT
SET link EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/(http.*)\./)[1];")
URL GOTO={{link}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shugar, your solution worked perfectly :)